# Show Process Tree very N seconds

Tags: linux, monitoring, ps

I would like to log the process tree of a linux server every second to a file.

This is the solution I have at the moment:

```
while true; do ps aux --forest  >> tmp/ps-aux-forest.log; sleep 1; done
```

I am missing:

- The output does not contain a timestamp on each line
- Every second a process for `ps` gets created.

I am not married with `ps`. Maybe there is a better tool. I want to avoid to write a shell script around `ps`.

This is just for temporary debugging. It should not run daily.

Any solution?

Comment: I think you can try `top`.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur I updated the question: I want to log to a file. AFAIK this does not work with top.

Answer (score 0):

Convert this statement:

```
do ps aux --forest
```

Into this:

```
ps aux --forest | while read p; do echo `date` "$p"; done
```

Bringing your full program to be this:

```
while true; do ps aux --forest | while read p; do echo `date` "$p" ; done; sleep 1; done
```